# Issue with "Empty Message" In a Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem with my Python script, which is a Discord bot. The script detects an "Empty Message", even though the message that has been sent into the server does have content, which are commands. Is there a way to fix this? I haven't found one yet.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if not message.content:
        print(f"Received empty message from user ID: {message.author.id}")
        return

    messages = [message]
    if message.reference is not None:
        referenced_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)
        if referenced_message.author == client.user and referenced_message.content.startswith('User ID: '):
            messages.insert(0, referenced_message)

    for msg in messages:
        print(f"Received message: '{msg.content}' from user ID: {msg.author.id}")

        if msg.content.startswith('!yes'):
            # Move approved data to a separate file (e.g., approved.json)
            with open('approved.json', 'a') as file:
                json.dump(data.pop(0), file, indent=4)
            await send_next_data()
            await msg.channel.send('Data approved.')
            print(f"User Approved the Shown User.")

        elif msg.content.startswith('!no'):
            # Move rejected data to a separate file (e.g., rejected.json)
            with open('rejected.json', 'a') as file:
                json.dump(data.pop(0), file, indent=4)
            await send_next_data()
            await msg.channel.send('Data rejected.')
            print(f"User Rejected the Shown User.")
```

I've added extra print parameters, such as `print(f"Received empty message from user ID: {message.author.id}")`, added `print(f"User Approved the Shown User.")` and `print(f"User Rejected the Shown User.")` and other small changes on other parts of the code.